# Prompt to save the text of richEditControl before select another tab on xtra.Tab

Tags: c#, controls, devexpress

I have a richEditControl, and I want to catch the event before user select another tab or other control. Is there any event to handle this ? So, if I wrote something (Text) in richEditControl, then if I try to do something else to show a Message dialog (etc Do you want to save this?)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the RichEditControl's [LostFocus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus?view=net-5.0) to be notified when a user clicks on another control or tab. If the RichEditControl's [Modified](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.RichEditControl.Modified) property is True, display your message box to prompt the user for saving.

Comment: I tried LostFocus but it show display message box when I try to change font. The problem is, that leave Event works correct If I dont use it with message box, but when show MessageBox is like stop event suddenly

Comment: You may have to display the MessageBox from a different thread.

Comment: How can I do this? Because, the problem is when I use MessageBox in event